# Flex Charting: Only display datatip for specific series?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a `LineChart` that contains multiple series, both `LineSeries` and `PlotSeries`, and I have a custom `dataTipFunction` set for the chart.  However, I only want data tips displayed for line series, not the plot series.  I have tried returning `null` from my format function, but that just displays an empty box.  I have also tried disable mouse events on the plot series (by setting both `mouseEnabled` and `mouseFocusEnabled` to `false`), to no avail.  Is this even possible?

Comment: love to find an answer before I ask :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `interactive` property of a *Series to `false`

```
<mx:series>
    <mx:LineSeries yField="Profit" form="curve" displayName="Profit"/>
    <mx:LineSeries yField="Expenses" form="curve" displayName="Expenses"/>
    <mx:LineSeries yField="Amount" form="curve" displayName="Amount"/>
    <mx:PlotSeries yField="Amount" interactive="false"/>
</mx:series>
```

Comment: Does the interactive field get ignored when showAllDataTips is set to true? I want to the same behavior, but I want the data tips to always be shown (except for 1 series)

Comment: This solution is not always satisfactory: setting interactive to false has a side effect that the chart element no longer generate hit data. If you need to detect chart element clicks, this is a problem.