# ShowAllDataTips only in a LineSeries

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6, lineseries

I have the next code

```
<mx:LineChart id="LEChart" width="900" height="600" 
                      showDataTips="true"  showAllDataTips="false"  
                      rollOver="lineChart_rollOver(event)"
                      rollOut="lineChart_rollOut(event)">                                       
            <!-- vertical axis -->
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis title="U/Uratedd" minimum="0.50" maximum="1.50"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>

            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:LogAxis id="LE70" interval="10" minimum="1000"  maximum="1.0E7" title="Life expectancy(h)"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxis>

            <!--<mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
                <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{LE70}" canDropLabels="true"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>-->                                        

            <mx:series>
                <mx:LineSeries dataProvider="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.arrLE70}" yField="zx" xField="fx" form="curve" displayName="Profit"/>
                <mx:LineSeries dataProvider="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.arrLE85}" yField="zx" xField="fx" form="curve" />
            </mx:series>    

        </mx:LineChart> 
        <mx:Legend dataProvider="{LEChart}" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
```

I get this graphic
http://subefotos.com/ver/?e9e23ef45417b02a7f7f5bd582574788o.png

Is It possible to show all data tips only in one lineserie when I put the mouse on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884123/flex-charting-only-display-datatip-for-specific-series

Comment: I think It's no solution for me because I have two line series (a and b). I want when I put the mouse on the a serie I can see the all data tips of the a line but if I put the mouse on the b serie I can't see the data tips of the a line and yes of the b line.  Thanks!